# Почему нельзя работать сразу со всеми библиотеками без их указания?

Tags: python, библиотеки, модули

Почему нужно указывать конкретные библиотеки, если есть нужда работать с ними? почему языки не могут работать сразу же со всеми модулями без их указания?

Answer (score 8):

Если бы Python подгружал все библиотеки сразу (например, встроенные), то простой запуск `print('Hello, world!')` съедал бы чересчур много памяти.

Потому что любая библиотека, которая импортируется в проект - это много кода, который нужно интерпретировать. И было бы не целесообразно, например, для программы реализующей функционал калькулятора держать код библиотеки flask (веб фреймворк), datetime (работа со временем и датой) и, например, pytorch (работа с нейронными сетями)

Comment: Пометьте вопрос как решение, пожалуйста

Answer (score 7):

Когда собираешься в лес за грибами, ты же не берешь с собой удочки, или ружье. Ведь ни рыбачить, ни охотится ты не будешь. Зачем перегружать свой багаж ненужными для конкретных целей вещами?

Так же и с языками программирования - из соображений эффективности, гибкости и экономии ресурсов.

Answer (score 3):

Просто ради пруфа концепта, можно использовать `__import__` -  это встроенная функция в Python, которая позволяет динамически импортировать модули и пакеты во время выполнения программы. В данном примере я нахожу то, что ставил с `pip` включая их зависимости и в цикле прогоняюсь по данному списку импортируя их в модуль. По сути данная конструкция позволит использовать *почти* все установленные библиотеки в рамках модуля.

```
import pipdeptree
import pkgutil

# Получаем список установленных библиотек и их зависимостей
dependencies = pipdeptree.get_installed_distributions()

# Создаем список установленных через pip библиотек
pip_libraries = [package.key for package in dependencies]

# Импортируем оставшиеся библиотеки из списка
for package_name in pip_libraries:
    try:
        module = __import__(package_name)
        print(f"Импортирована библиотека: {package_name}")
    except ImportError:
        print(f"Не удалось импортировать библиотеку: {package_name}")
    except:
        print(f"Ошибки библиотеки: {package_name}")
```

*P.S. потому что почему бы и нет? никто тебя не ограничивает в действиях.*

Comment: Если там попадётся, например, matplotlib, то только он будет импортироваться примерно секунду (!). То есть при использовании такого подхода программа будет *очень долго* запускаться. ))

Comment: @wchistow да, а некоторые библы вообще будут дичь творить, например у меня есть какая-то библа которая открывает ссылку в браузере с комиксами от xkcd, я понятия не имел что у меня есть такая, пока я не запустил все библы разом, но всё же, ПоЧеМу Бы И нЕт?